# Adding reactions to messages with switch statements

Tags: node.js, switch-statement, discord, discord.js

I'm planning on adding multiple reaction commands in my discord bot (as it's created for fun, so I wish to have fun things for people to find via it) and I wish to turn it to switch statements so I can properly see which goes where, without the bulk of if statements. Here's what my code currently looks like with if statements, and what I've used with switch statements that somewhat worked, though not completely. (though with different includes and emojis, as it's quite embarrassing what I currently have)

```
if (message.content.includes('test')) {
        message.react("")
```

```
    switch (message.content.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'test':
            message.react("")
            break;
}
```

That worked somewhat, having the react to anything containing ONLY the word "test" despite capitalization, but for this bot I want it to detect the word anywhere in the message, so I decided trying:

```
    switch (message.content.includes()) {
        case 'test': 
            message.react("")
            break;
```

But that ended up not working at all

Any advice how to have this work with switch statements, or should I stick with else if statements, despite wanting a large amount of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const messageToLower = message.content.toLowerCase(); 

switch(true) {
    case messageToLower.includes('test'): message.react("");break;
}
```

Should work since includes() need to have a value.
If you want multiple values checked I'd suggest.

```
var item=[{id:"test",message:""},{id:"stuff",message:""}, 
{id:"t",message:""}];
function message(item,messageToLower){
    for(var i=0; i< item.length; i++){
        if(item[i].id==messageToLower){
           message.react(item[i].message);
           break;
        }
    }
}

const messageToLower = message.content.toLowerCase(); 
message(messageToLower);
```

Comment: Thank you!! The first part worked perfectly for what I wanted ^^

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```js
const reactToMessage = message => {
  const messageTriggers = {
    'cat': () => {
      message.react('')
    },
    'dog': () => {
      message.react('')
    },
    'cow': () => {
      message.react('')
    }
  }

  Object.keys(messageTriggers).forEach(trigger => {
    message.toLowerCase().includes(trigger) && messageTriggers[trigger]()
  })
}

// Usage
reactToMessage('Cat and dog goes to Cow!')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, includes() returns a boolean, so case would need to be True or False. I would wrap your switch in a function and wrap that in a for loop:

```
triggerArray = ["test", "this", "that"];
triggerArray.forEach(myFunc);
function myFunc(item){
  switch (message.content.includes()) {
    case 'test': 
        message.react("")
        break;
  }
}
```